# CPU Not completely Utilized in large workload

Tags: performance, cpu, macos, benchmark

I have a **Macbook Pro** with a **i9 Processor** and running Macos Catalina. I run CPU extensive tasks daily, but it never utilizes 100% of the CPU. I use `Intel Power Gadget` to check out my CPU performance. [image: Screenshot of Intel Power Gadget] Utilization never reaches 100%. Yet when I run the `Cine-bench Bench-mark` it reaches 100%. Can I know why this doesn't happen when I run any other regular app which must consume 100% utilization in order to actually run faster. **I also made sure the software I am running is optimized in a way it can acquire many cores as possible.** Hope you can share any configuration files that must be changed to in order for all processes capable of utilizing 100% of the CPU.

Comment: "I also made sure the software I am running is optimized in a way it can acquire many cores as possible." I assume the process(es) you're running completely reside in user space. The kernel scheduler is ultimately responsible for distributing CPU resources among threads. A process that lives in user space does not have the ultimate say in how many CPU resources it can absorb for a given chunk of time. So what do you really mean by "optimized?"

Comment: Are you sure that the process you are trying to run is sufficiently compute-intensive to use 100% of the CPU? It must be multi-threaded in a way that does not cause one thread to ever wait for a resource held by another thread, it cannot access the network or file system, etc.?